# Put a video in a View and play it Aspnet.core

Tags: html, asp.net-core

I have an exercise class and a view that allows me to create exercises.
One of the variables is a video, how can you insert a video in order to save it in the database and present it in the view?
In exercise class I have

```
[Table("Exercicios_Ginasio")]
    public partial class ExerciciosGinasio
    {
        public ExerciciosGinasio()
        {
            Inclui = new HashSet<Inclui>();
        }

        [Key]
        [Column("IDExercicios_Ginasio")]
        public int IdexerciciosGinasio { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("nome")]
        [StringLength(30)]
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("texto_descritivo")]
        [StringLength(1000)]
        public string TextoDescritivo { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("foto")]

        public string Foto { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("video")]

        public string Video { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("IdexerciciosGinasioNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<Inclui> Inclui { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In the controller Exercises I used the function Create automatically generated in the creation of the controller
In the method I added code to save the image in the database

```
  [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("IdexerciciosGinasio,Nome,TextoDescritivo,Foto,Video")] ExerciciosGinasio exerciciosGinasio, IFormFile fotografia,IFormFile video)
        {
            string caminho = Path.Combine(_hostEnviroment.ContentRootPath, "wwwroot\\Exercicios");

            string nome_ficheiro = Path.GetFileName(fotografia.FileName);
            string caminho_completo = Path.Combine(caminho, nome_ficheiro);

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(caminho_completo, FileMode.Create);
            fotografia.CopyTo(fs);
            exerciciosGinasio.Foto = caminho_completo;
            fs.Close();




            string caminho2 = Path.Combine(_hostEnviroment.ContentRootPath, "wwwroot\\Exercicios");

            string nome_ficheiro2 = Path.GetFileName(video.FileName);
            string caminho_completo2 = Path.Combine(caminho2, nome_ficheiro2);

            FileStream _fs = new FileStream(caminho_completo2, FileMode.Create);
            video.CopyTo(_fs);
            exerciciosGinasio.Video = caminho_completo2;
            _fs.Close();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                _context.Add(exerciciosGinasio);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(exerciciosGinasio);
        }
```

So how do I put it in the view to insert a video and save it in the database?
In order to be able to present it in the index

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.ExerciciosGinasio

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}
<h4>Criar Exercicio</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Nome" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Nome" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Nome" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="TextoDescritivo" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="TextoDescritivo" type="text" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="TextoDescritivo" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Foto" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Foto" type="file" class="form-control" accept=".png, .jpg, .bmp" value="" />
                @*<span asp-validation-for="Foto" class="text-danger"></span>*@

                <div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="fotografia" value="0" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Video" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Video" type="file" class="form-control" />
                    @*<span asp-validation-for="Video" class="text-danger"></span>*@
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="video" value="0" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div>
    <a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home">Voltar</a>
</div>

<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

I tested it this way, and I got this error

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
WebApplication1.Controllers.ExerciciosGinasiosController.Create(ExerciciosGinasio exerciciosGinasio, IFormFile fotografia, IFormFile video) in ExerciciosGinasiosController.cs, line 64

```
WebApplication1.Controllers.ExerciciosGinasiosController.Create(ExerciciosGinasio exerciciosGinasio, IFormFile fotografia, IFormFile video) in ExerciciosGinasiosController.cs
   string nome_ficheiro = Path.GetFileName(fotografia.FileName);
```

Can someone help me solve it?

Comment: I think the transfer of video is no different from transferring files to a server.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer is not working, and if I use how do I save the image?